# IBM Worklight v5.0.6 Application Center - apk file upload fails

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When attempting to upload our apk file, the server responds back with simply

"File HelloWorld.apk file not uploaded"

Nothing is logged in trace.log in relation to this upload, so not able to see any type of log message to diagnose further.  How do you enable logging for this?

Is there a timeout, or file upload size limit?  If so, how/where do you change that?  The HelloWorld.apk file size is 5.6MB

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a filesize limit, but it is imposed by MySQL by default (1MB). If you are using MySQL 5.1 or 5.5 (5.6 is not supported in Worklight 5.0.x). follow these steps:

1. Locate the file `my.ini` belonging to your MySQL installation
2. In it, find the section `[mysqld]`
3. Underneath the section name, paste this: `max_allowed_packet=1000M`
4. Re-start the MySQL service
5. Re-deploy the .apk file

You may need to re-start the application server running Application Center as well.